# When exactly do calendars repeat themselves (Gregorian)?

Tags: math, calendar, gregorian-calendar

After how many years exactly do we get the same calendar as the current year?
When can I safely reuse my calendar again for the present year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link 
http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/repeating.html - there is no definitive answer (2016's calendar matches every +/-28 years for some time, where 2015's does not match years as periodically (+6,+6, +11, ...).

On a further note: due to the calculation of holidays (e.g. Easter is the first Sunday after the first full moon in Spring [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter#Computations ] ) holidays will not easily repeat periodically either.

Comment: Since you only want the days of week repeating the holidays is not an issue here.
I would proceed by checking whether or not the input `y` is a leap year and if that is the case try the next years by checking `y + 4`, `y + 8` (and so on) now if the first day of the year is the same day of week you should be done. This omits checking if the "destination" year is also a leap year, but could be easily checked by comparing the last day of the year. 
If it is not a leap year you'd only have to check other "non-leap years" by checking if the first day of the year matches your query.

Comment: Well, the idea seems perfect! Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

The Gregorian calendar has a period of 400 years (146,097 days).